# I am getting these errors: "property value expected" & "at-rule or selector expected"

Tags: html, css

So as the title says, I am getting these errors: "property value expected" & "at-rule or selector expected". I do not understand what this means as I'm only a beginner, I tried looking for answers but none seem to work. This is only happening in my CSS file.

Here is my current CSS code:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
}

.app {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 100vh;
    align-items: center;
}

.calculator{
    background-color: #22252D;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 375px;
    min-height: 640px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    border-radius: 1.5rem;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.display{
    min-height: 200px;
    padding: 1.5rem;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    align-items: flex-end;
    color: white;
    text-align: right;
    flex: 1 1 0%;
}

.display .input{
    font-size: 1.25rem;
    margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
}

.display .output{
    font-size: 3rem;
    font-weight: bold;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}

.display .operator{
    color: #66666;
}
```

This happens in the last three lines of code, where I call the .display .operator classes.

Comment: Should be `.display .operator{color: #666666;}` I guess.  6 digits.

Comment: I cannot believe I didn't see that, thank you very much lol.